# Do you need to call the constructor for class objects in Systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I have a class with an element in the class being another class.  Do I need to call the constructor of the element inside the constructor for the class itself?  For example:

```
class my_class;
  element_class A;

  function new ();
    A = new(123);
  endfunction
endclass


class element_class;
  int B;

  function new(int init_value);
    B = init_value;
  endfunction
endclass
```

Is the constructor call in "my_class" needed or can you just do the following:

```
class my_class;
  element_class A;

  function new ();
    A.B = 123;
  endfunction
endclass


class element_class;
  int B;

  function new(int init_value);
    B = init_value;
  endfunction
endclass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classes in SystemVerilog need to call their constructors before you can reference any member of that class object.

Comment: It will compile and _run_ up until it tries to access `A.B`. Then you will get a run-time reference error because the class variable `A` is **null**.